# xUnit testing framework for C

Tags: c, xunit, check-framework

I'm developing a fairly simple C project for an embedded device. I'd like to employ xUnit testing. I've settled down with the Check framework (http://check.sourceforge.net/), but it seems it doesn't support function stubs. I remember using a very syntactically similar framework a few years ago that supported stubs, but i can't remember its name.

So, can anyone suggest an xUnit framework for C that supports stubs? A way to imitate stubs while using Check library would be OK, too.

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what do you mean by function stubs?

Comment: I want to be able to substitute certain function calls with my own ones.

E.g., let's consider a case when i need to take a look at my program's behaviour when file() returns NULL. So, i want to be able to implement a file_fail() stub and then tell the framework to replace all file() calls with file_fail() ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cgreen supports mock functions, is this what you want?

https://cgreen-devs.github.io/#_what_are_mock_functions

Comment: I guess this solution is the closest to what i need... Albeit not exactly :)